# What about server OS questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, super-user

Currently on Super User is this question: [Search content of files with unknown extension](https://superuser.com/questions/166817/seach-content-of-files-with-unknown-extension)

The question is asking how to do things with the search tool, in Windows Server 2008. I was wondering if this question should be migrated to SF or not.

In general, I know that this is not really a matter of sysadmin, it's really a "user task". However, it's directed to an OS which is normally used only by sysadmins (and a few home servers). So in theory, the Server Fault community is more likely to know the answer to such a question.

So here is the general question, aside from my particular case:

- What about questions on Super User which are related to a server OS? *(And I really mean a professional server one, not one which would be used as a home server)*.
- Should we migrate them to Server Fault, if they don't get an answer on Super User?
- Or is it really a user matter, and it would clutter Server Fault?

Comment: *"And I really mean a professional server one, not one which would be used as a home server"*

In school we got Windows Server ISOs from MSDN.  I can assure you that I was running the "professional" server OS on my home machines. :)

Comment: @jscott - yes, this I meant with the "a few home servers". The other sentence was more about Windows Home Server :-]

Comment: "In general, I know that this is not really a matter of sysadmin, it's really a 'user task'" - Sounds pretty clear cut to me.

Answer (score 5):

I personally wouldn't be against migrating that question.  Configuring the Windows Search Service on a file server or Terminal server used by many users is something that an administrator may want/need to do.

The question you linked to for Windows 7 does seem to work under 2008.  But there doesn't appear to be any way to include all files.  That procedure appears to only seem to allow you to index specific types.

The way the question is written doesn't seem to be purely about a single end-user.  I am not sure if there is an answer though.  A correct answer may actually come from stackoverflow.  I am not entirely sure if it is even possible to get all files without writing a new filter to for the search service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318649(VS.85).aspx) on 2008.

If someone wanted to exeriment one could try adding the [plain-text persistence filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940433(VS.85).aspx#find_file_dll) to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes* and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

I think the question could live quite happily on either site, since it's a shared 2008/7 feature, and either community probably has a fair shake at having the same knowhow.  But then again, I'm comfortable with the gray area between the sites, where a host of questions can fall.  I know others are more in favor of a sharp line of separation, and I can't say which is correct, really.

Comment: +1 , I agree that some overlap is fine. Trying to make too sharp of division feels unnecessary to me.  I think that is part of the reason it takes 5 votes to move something ... the idea being don't move it unless it really needs to be moved.